# Node.js Windows Installer

Tags: windows, node.js

I've installed Nodejs using the Windows installer from the node.js site but was unable to run the node command in the command prompt.

Also I couldn't find a folder in c:\Program Files\nodejs

Is there a place I can find it so I can include in my system path?

Comment: Did the installer not present a folder dialog filled in with the default path?  Try searching for it?  You have the machine here, how can we find it if you cannot??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running a 64bit version Windows you should look in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
```

Comment: This is true for 32bit installer versions. If you are using 64bit Windows installer it is C:\Program Files\nodejs